# EXCEL - Calculating difference between military times to derive minutes

Tags: excel, time

This is for a graduate project I am working on, and I would greatly appreciate it any help!Let me just say that I am not familiar with VBA, and I know that this can be done with a simple formula.  I am trying to calculate the amount of time that a person has spent in bed.  This is an old note I had explaining how to calculate the values I need, but for some reason it is not working.

*The time in bed formula should be the difference between lights out and time out of bed. I have an old note that this formula should be:

 ** Calculating time in bed duration (in minutes) from two military time-formatted values **
A1=time in bed; B1=time out of bed
=(24*IF(B1>A1, B1-A1, 1-A1+B1))*60*

Can anyone help me refine this function so it works properly, or help me formulate a new one?

Comment: https://www.google.com/?q=excel+difference+between+two+times

Comment: Thank you, but im not sure that I can alter the times.  Do you understand the formula I supplied in the question? If so, maybe we can refine it until it works???

Comment: you must have no soul.  there is nothing on google that will explicitly explain how to derive the variables i need.

Comment: `=Time(Left(B1, 2), Right(B1, 2), 0) - Time(Left(A1, 2), Right(A1, 2), 0)`

Comment: `This is for a graduate project` Does this mean you should go and tag it as 'homework'?

Answer (score 3):

I think I have the solution you are looking for. All times in excel(whether military or standard) are represented as a decimal number between 0 and 1. Once you know that it is just a matter of making a formula to subtract the two:

```
=IF(((C6/(1/24))-(B6/(1/24)))<0,24+((C6/(1/24))-(B6/(1/24))),((C6/(1/24))-(B6/(1/24))))
```

[image: Excel Timesheet Example]

If you want to do it for minutes you would just alter that formula like so:

```
=IF(((C6/(24*60))-(B6/(24*60)))<0,(24*60)+((C6/(24*60))-(B6/(24*60))),((C6/(24*60))-(B6/(24*60))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean by "military times" in this context - what do the times look like exactly? If the time values are valid time values in Excel (however formatted) then you can use this variation on your formula

`=1440*IF(B1>A1,B1-A1,1-A1+B1)`

For example if start time is 11:00 PM and end time 08:15 AM then that formula will give the result 555 (the time difference in minutes)

this shorter formula should also do the same

`=1440*MOD(B1-A1,1)`

If by "military time" you mean that your times don't have colons, e.g. 2300 and 0815 then you can use this variation on the second formula

`=1440*MOD(TEXT(B1,"00\:00")-TEXT(A1,"00\:00"),1)`

Answer (score 0):

Folks,

As long as the times are formatted as `nn:nn` (military time with a colon), do this:

Format all cells as `TIME>13:30` (13:30 is the military time format and is the 2nd item on the format dropdown under TIME)

Cell A1 has the first time

Cell B1 has the second time

Cell C1 is a formula: `=(2400-A1)+B1`

Answer (score -1):

```
=IF(A1>B1,    
((2300-ROUNDDOWN(A1,-2))/100*60)+(ROUNDDOWN(B1,-2)/100)*60,                                   
((ROUNDDOWN(B1,-2)/100)-(ROUNDDOWN(A1,-2)/100))*60)+                   
IF(A1>B1,60-RIGHT(A1,2)+RIGHT(B1,2),RIGHT(B1,2)-RIGHT(A1,2))
```

This will give you the time between any two time periods entered in START-A1 and END-B1. For 1200 midnight it is 0, for 1205=5.